# Setting names from list elements as a column when using bind_rows/data.frame

Tags: r

I am trying to process a number of lists and I am losing the `names` of some of the list elements.

The list looks like:

```
> myLists2
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
                         title                        company                     date_range                       location 
            "Founder | Co-CEO"                  "someCompany" "ene. de 2018 \023 actualidad"                       "Europe" 
                   description                 li_company_url 
          "some description 1"       "https://www.google.com" 

[[2]][[2]]
                         title                        company                     date_range                       location 
               "Another title"                 "someCompany2" "ene. de 2019 \023 actualidad"                          "USA" 
                   description                 li_company_url 
         "Another Description"        "https://www.yahoo.com" 

[[2]][[3]]
                          title                         company                      date_range                        location 
              "Another title 3"             "Another company 3" "sept. de 2018 \023 actualidad"                        "Europe" 
                    description                  li_company_url 
        "Another description 3" "https://www.stackexchange.com"
```

Where if I run `names(myLists2[[2]][[1]])` I get the following:

```
[1] "title"          "company"        "date_range"     "location"       "description"    "li_company_url"
```

The number of names can slightly vary over the different lists and I would like to create a new column where the `names` appear in a `data.frame`.

Running:

```
hh <- myLists2[[2]] %>% data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column("tag")
```

Gives me a nice data frame where I use the `rownames_to_column()` function to save the rownames, however this gives me an error when the list elements are different lengths.

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
> check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 5,
> 6

A solution I found to this was to use `bind_rows()`. Running:

```
myLists2[[2]] %>% bind_rows()
```

Gives me a `tibble` but I lose the `names` from the lists. Running:

```
myLists2[[2]] %>% bind_rows(.id = "myID")
```

Does not seem to solve the issue either since it just gives me a new column from 1 to 3.

My question is, how can I use the `bind_rows()` (which are not sensitive to differing column lengths) and also save the `names` from the lists as a column?

Data:

```
myLists2 <- list(NULL, list(c(title = "Founder | Co-CEO", company = "someCompany", 
                              date_range = "ene. de 2018 \023 actualidad", location = "Europe", 
                              description = "some description 1", li_company_url = "https://www.google.com"
), c(title = "Another title", company = "someCompany2", date_range = "ene. de 2019 \023 actualidad", 
     location = "USA", description = "Another Description", li_company_url = "https://www.yahoo.com"
), c(title = "Another title 3", company = "Another company 3", 
     date_range = "sept. de 2018 \023 actualidad", location = "Europe", 
     description = "Another description 3", li_company_url = "https://www.stackexchange.com"
)))
```

EDIT: (Adding a new list)

```
myNewList <- list(list(c(title = "Founder | Co-CEO", company = "some company", 
            date_range = "ene. de 2018 \023 actualidad", location = "Europe", 
            description = "some description", 
            li_company_url = "https://www.google.com"
), c(title = "some thing here", company = "some company", 
     date_range = "ene. de 2019 \023 actualidad", location = "USA", 
     description = "another description", 
     li_company_url = "https://www.yahoo.com")
), list(c(title = "CEO", company = "another company", 
           date_range = "2012 \023 actualidad", description = "some other description", 
           li_company_url = ""), c(title = "job title", 
                                   company = "company name", date_range = "ene. de 2005 \023 actualidad", 
                                   location = "Europe", description = "company description", 
                                   li_company_url = "https://www.yahoo.com"), 
         c(title = "job title 2", company = "company name", date_range = "1995 \023 actualidad", 
           description = "description", 
           li_company_url = ""), c(title = "job title", 
                                   company = "company name", date_range = "1992 \023 1995", 
                                   location = "USA", description = "soem company description", 
                                   li_company_url = ""), c(title = "company title", company = "company name", 
                                                           date_range = "1990 \023 1992", description = "Another description", 
                                                           li_company_url = "")), NULL)
```

These show the problems I am running into:

```
map(myNewList, ~data.frame(.x))
map(myNewList[1], ~data.frame(.x)) # runs okay and I keep the names
map(myNewList[2], ~data.frame(.x)) # errors
map(myNewList, ~bind_rows(.x))    # runs okay but I lsoe the names
```

Comment: Maybe is this what you are looking for? `do.call(bind_rows,lapply(myLists2,function(x) {x <- x %>% data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column("tag");return(x)}))`

Comment: I still get the `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 6` - I will try and update the list to reproduce this error.

Comment: Yeah I ran over your list and worked!

Comment: I added a new list.

Comment: I have added a sketch that can be useful, I hope that can be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `map_if` with `data.table::transpose` after doing the `bind_rows`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(data.table)
map_if(myNewList, .p = ~ length(.) > 0,
                .f =  ~bind_rows(.x) %>% 
                         data.table::transpose(., keep.names = 'title') %>%
                         column_to_rownames('title'),
                 .else = ~ NA_character_)
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#                                         V1                           V2
#title                      Founder | Co-CEO              some thing here
#company                        some company                 some company
#date_range     ene. de 2018 \023 actualidad ene. de 2019 \023 actualidad
#location                             Europe                          USA
#description                some description          another description
#li_company_url       https://www.google.com        https://www.yahoo.com

#[[2]]
#                                   V1                           V2                   V3                       V4
#title                             CEO                    job title          job title 2                job title
#company               another company                 company name         company name             company name
#date_range       2012 \023 actualidad ene. de 2005 \023 actualidad 1995 \023 actualidad           1992 \023 1995
#description    some other description          company description          description soem company description
#li_company_url                               https://www.yahoo.com                                              
#location                         <NA>                       Europe                 <NA>                      USA
#                                V5
#title                company title
#company               company name
#date_range          1990 \023 1992
#description    Another description
#li_company_url                    
#location                      <NA>

#[[3]]
#[1] NA
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying many options I found a rustic method to obtain what you want. It uses `rbind.fill()` function from `plyr` so be careful when loading the package as `dplyr` has conflicts with it. The main idea (that uses a loop) transform your valus to a dataframe, then transpose to have columns and can bind by rows so that empty space can be filled with `NA` (that is why we used the `plyr` function). The pro is that in the loop you can manage the `NULL` elements with a conditional. Here the code with the new data you shared:

```
library(plyr)
#Create a list to store the results
List <- list()
#Loop index2
for(i in 1:length(myNewList))
{
  v <- length(myNewList[[i]])
  #Conditional
  if(v==0)
  {
    List[[i]] <- NA
  } else
  {
    #Check length for NULL elements
    #First transform to dataframe in a column format
    #This will make easy to join
    O1 <- lapply(myNewList[[i]],function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))
    #Now bind all with rbind.fill to avoid issues with different number of variables you had
    O2 <- do.call(rbind.fill,O1)
    #Finally transpose to have a format similar to what you want
    O3 <- as.data.frame(t(O2))
    #Save in List
    List[[i]] <- O3
  }
}
```

Output:

```
List
[[1]]
                                         V1                           V2
title                      Founder | Co-CEO              some thing here
company                        some company                 some company
date_range     ene. de 2018 \023 actualidad ene. de 2019 \023 actualidad
location                             Europe                          USA
description                some description          another description
li_company_url       https://www.google.com        https://www.yahoo.com

[[2]]
                                   V1                           V2                   V3
title                             CEO                    job title          job title 2
company               another company                 company name         company name
date_range       2012 \023 actualidad ene. de 2005 \023 actualidad 1995 \023 actualidad
description    some other description          company description          description
li_company_url                               https://www.yahoo.com                     
location                         <NA>                       Europe                 <NA>
                                     V4                  V5
title                         job title       company title
company                    company name        company name
date_range               1992 \023 1995      1990 \023 1992
description    soem company description Another description
li_company_url                                             
location                            USA                <NA>

[[3]]
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility using only `purrr`, `dplyr` and `tibble`:

```r
myNewList %>%
    map_if(~!is.null(.), 
           function(mylist) map(mylist, 
                                ~data.frame(.x) %>% 
                                     rownames_to_column("tag")) %>% 
                                 reduce(full_join, by = "tag"))
[[1]]
             tag                         .x.x                         .x.y
1          title             Founder | Co-CEO              some thing here
2        company                 some company                 some company
3     date_range ene. de 2018 \023 actualidad ene. de 2019 \023 actualidad
4       location                       Europe                          USA
5    description             some description          another description
6 li_company_url       https://www.google.com        https://www.yahoo.com

[[2]]
             tag                   .x.x                         .x.y               .x.x.x                   .x.y.y                  .x
1          title                    CEO                    job title          job title 2                job title       company title
2        company        another company                 company name         company name             company name        company name
3     date_range   2012 \023 actualidad ene. de 2005 \023 actualidad 1995 \023 actualidad           1992 \023 1995      1990 \023 1992
4    description some other description          company description          description soem company description Another description
5 li_company_url                               https://www.yahoo.com                                                                  
6       location                   <NA>                       Europe                 <NA>                      USA                <NA>

[[3]]
NULL
```

Or removing empty lists:

```r
inter_list <- map(myNewList, function(mylist) map(mylist, ~data.frame(.x) %>% rownames_to_column("tag")))
nullw <- which(map_lgl(inter_list, ~length(.x)==0))
if(length(nullw)!=0) inter_list <- inter_list[-nullw]
map(inter_list, ~reduce(.x, full_join, by = "tag"))

[[1]]
             tag                         .x.x                         .x.y
1          title             Founder | Co-CEO              some thing here
2        company                 some company                 some company
3     date_range ene. de 2018 \023 actualidad ene. de 2019 \023 actualidad
4       location                       Europe                          USA
5    description             some description          another description
6 li_company_url       https://www.google.com        https://www.yahoo.com

[[2]]
             tag                   .x.x                         .x.y               .x.x.x                   .x.y.y                  .x
1          title                    CEO                    job title          job title 2                job title       company title
2        company        another company                 company name         company name             company name        company name
3     date_range   2012 \023 actualidad ene. de 2005 \023 actualidad 1995 \023 actualidad           1992 \023 1995      1990 \023 1992
4    description some other description          company description          description soem company description Another description
5 li_company_url                               https://www.yahoo.com                                                                  
6       location                   <NA>                       Europe                 <NA>                      USA                <NA>
```